# Why does ''.split(' ') return [''] but ''.split() returns []?

Tags: python, string, split

Why does `''.split(' ')` return `['']` but `''.split()` return `[]`?

I understand that `split` will return original string if no match

Since there is no space in empty strings, I would expect both to return the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [split](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method uses 2 different algorithms depending on if the `sep` argument is passed:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.